i want to make an animated arrow in html/css
I want to make this arrow animation. I want it to be centered and align the three lines that make the arrow shape. I want it to be smooth.
I'd like the three lines (that make the arrow) to align perfectly and in the middle. Also I used the border of the lines container as reference but now if I remove it — all the lines are out of position.
.line-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid;
}


.line {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--line-color);
    border-radius: 50px;
    
}
.l1{
    animation: drawLine 2s linear infinite;
    width: 10px;
}
@keyframes drawLine {
    0% {
        height: 2px;
        top: 50px;
    }
    50% {
        height: 70px;
        top: 50px;
    }
    100% {
        height: 0px;
        top: 120px;}
}
.l2{
    transform-origin: top left;
    animation: drawAndEraseDiagonal 2s linear infinite; 
    height: 10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
@keyframes drawAndEraseDiagonal {
    0% {
        width: 2px;
        top: 90px;
        left: 80px;
    }
    50% {
        width: 40px;
        top: 90px;
        left: 80px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 2px;
        top: 115px;
        left: 100px;
    }
    
}
.l3{
    transform-origin: top right;
    animation: drawAndEraseDiagonal1 2s linear infinite; 
    height: 10px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
@keyframes drawAndEraseDiagonal1 {
    0% {
        width: 2px;
        top: 90px;
        right: 70px;
    }
    50% {
        width: 40px;
        top: 90px;
        right: 70px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 2px;
        top: 115px;
        right: 90px;
        
    }
}

this is a link to the hole thing :https://codepen.io/TUSK-ACT-4-the-typescripter/pen/wvLPaPR

Please put the code as a runnable snippet into your question and please check that it does show the problem.

Please click [edit], then click the button marked [<>] and create a [mcve] here

Also please be clearer about what you want to remove. The codepen looks like it works
